# How to make XML from an object

Tags: java, xml, object, kotlin, xml-parsing

I wanna ask that how to generate xml from object?

let's say if it's json, i just need to use jaskson or Gson

```
json = someObj.writeValueAsString
```

but then for xml that i search through the internet, it seems like it needs to construst the document first? like write it into a streamwriter then output to some dir become a file (xxx.xml)?

**But my purpose is to construst(from an object) & parse the xml to other RESTful API.**

And also if someone can help with the parsing i would be very happy. I mean like how to call Http Request and put the xml into the body and fire to some url.

```
val url = "https://api.mch.weixin.qq.com/pay/unifiedorder"
        val headers = HttpHeaders()
        headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML
val xmlMapper = XmlMapper()
        var strObject = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(wxPayOrderWithSign).replace(Regex("<[^>]*?/>"), "")

        strObject = strObject.substring(12,strObject.length - 13)
        strObject = "<xml>$strObject</xml>"

        val entity = HttpEntity(strObject, headers)


        val respEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String::class.java)
        val return_msg = respEntity.body
```

here its my code in kotlin, but this is not the correct method as i use regex to replace some character during the conversion of object to string.

i need to generate something like

```
<xml>
<appid>wx0b6d2803d20b379f1</appid>
<body>QQMember-TopUp</body>
<detail>test</detail>
<mch_id>1508478951</mch_id>
<nonce_str>c9c21120a9724ee993e6f9c866ec30e1</nonce_str>
<notify_url>http://wxpay.wxutil.com/pub_v2/pay/notify.v2.php</notify_url>
<out_trade_no>20150806125346</out_trade_no>
<sign>6E18248C5FFA26D1A96BD8F6A0B0CB02</sign>
<spbill_create_ip>123.12.12.123</spbill_create_ip>
<total_fee>1</total_fee>
<trade_type>JSAPI</trade_type>
</xml>
```

Comment: btw, java code also ok for me.

Comment: If you are used to Jackson, you may use it for serializing to and deserializing from XML as well, you just need to use an additional mapping module: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Answer (score 2):

JAXB come with java sdk since version 6 and provides a easy way to mashalling and unmashalling java objects:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Transaction {

    private Long id;
    private Float value;
    private Boolean authorized;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.setId(1L);
        transaction.setValue(20.9f);
        transaction.setAuthorized(true);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Transaction.class );
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true );

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal( transaction, new File( "transaction.xml" ) );//save to file
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal( transaction, System.out ); //send to stdout
        //raw xml as string
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal( transaction, writer);
        String rawXml = writer.toString();

    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<transaction>
    <authorized>true</authorized>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>20.9</value>
</transaction>
```

Using RestTemplate, you can just pass the object which should sent as XML in the HttpEntity constructor, like:

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.setId(1L);
transaction.setValue(20.9f);
transaction.setAuthorized(true);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
HttpEntity<Transaction> request = new HttpEntity<Transaction>(transaction, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/xml/transactions", request, String.class);
```

Comment: how about if i want it in a string instead of output it to a file?
thanks for reply anyways

Comment: @SicaYoumi the `marshal` method has several overloads, one of which allows you to write to a `Writer`. You can use it to marshal to a `StringWriter` and then you can call `toString` on your writer to get the XML as a `String`

Comment: @user2340612 hey about that, thanks bro, i managed to get it, but when i  compile and run it gives me an

Parameter 1 of constructor in {{my root package}} required a bean of type 'javax.xml.bind.Marshaller' that could not be found.

I tried to find solution, ppl say want to add the bean configuration but .... i find everywhere in my spring project, i could not find spring context, and add the config XML

Comment: Like @user2340612 said, you can use a StringWriter to do that, I added the code to the answer